# Reading the contents of a file based on character position

Tags: linux, bash

If I have a file with the sentence:

```
I like apples and oranges

but I hate broccoli
```

How would I go about storing to a variable the following string from the file:

```
ut I hate broc
```

I have tried using `mycut=$(cut -c 2-15 file)`, but this cuts from both lines in the file `(mycut == "I like apples a ut I hate broc")`. I only want to grab the string those specific character positions from that specific line. Is there some way I can do this?

If there is a better way other than using cut, that's fine too.

Comment: How do you know which line you want? Is it always line #2? Is it always the one containing "broccoli"?

Comment: The line doesn't necessarily have to be the 2nd one. I want to be able to specify which line and character position.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading contents of a file based on character position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51276449/reading-contents-of-a-file-based-on-character-position)

Comment: You shouldn't ask the exact same question twice. You should wait for the now improved question to be reopened instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a valid solution with AWK:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{ lineIwant = 2; beginChar = 1; finalChar = 3}{ if( NR ==lineIwant ) { print substr($0,beginChar,finalChar)}}' file.txt
```

Regards!

Comment: This is an valid solution that will **only** work when `beginChar=1`. The reason is that `substr` is not called as `substr(string,begin,end)` but as `substr(string,begin,length)`.

Comment: @kvantour yep. you are right. miss on my part. Anyway the last parameter can be omitted.

Comment: @kvantour yep. you are right. miss on my part. Anyway the last parameter can be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` is your friend.

```
$: cat x
I like apples and oranges

but I hate broccoli
$: l=3
$: s=1
$: r=14
$: sed -nE "$l { s/^.{$s}(.{$r}).*/\\1/; p; q; }" x
ut I hate broc
```

I'm using `-n` to suppress output I don't want, and -E for extended expressions. Double-quotes let me embed the variables, so I could try different values for line($l), skip($s), and repeat($r).

I told it to *only on line `$l`*, use s/// to remove leading and trailing data, then print the line and quit. The `{...}` groups all the commands so none occur on any other line.

Answer (score 1):

Cut command have -c option for this and you can specify line by  `head -n | tail -1`:

```
echo "I like apples and oranges
But i hate broccoli" |head -2|tail -1|cut -c 2-15
```

results:

```
ut i hate broc
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you find a couple of Awk lines that might help to get information of textfiles.

**Counting characters/words/lines/sentences/paragraphs:**

```
awk '{n++}END{print n}' file                             # lines
awk '{n+=NF}END{print n}' file                           # words
awk '{n+=length($0)}END{print n}' file                   # characters    
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}{n++}END{print n}' file                 # paragraphs
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="[.?!]+"}{n+=NF}END{print n}' file   # sentences
```

**Retrieve `n`th character/word/line/sentence/paragraph:**

```
awk '(NR==n){print; exit}' file                             # line
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}(NR==n){print;exit}' file                  # paragraph
awk 'BEGIN{c=n}(c-NF<=0){print $c; exit}{c-=NF}' file       # word
# character
awk 'BEGIN{c=n}(c-length($0)<=0){print substr($0,c,1); exit}{c-=length($0)}' file
# sentence
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="[.?!]+";c=n}(c-NF<=0){print $c; exit}{c-=NF}' file
```

**Retrieve `p`th character/word in line `n`:**

```
awk '(NR==n){print $p; exit}' file               # word
awk '(NR==n){print substr($0,p,1); exit}' file   # character
```

**Retrieve all characters/words from `p` in line `n`:**

```
awk '(NR==n){print substr($0,p); exit}' file                            # character
awk '(NR==n){for(i=p;i<NF;++i) printf $i OFS;print $NF; exit}' file     # word
```

**Retrieve characters/words `p` to `q` in line `n`:**

```
awk '(NR==n){print substr($0,p,q-p+1); exit}' file #character
# word
awk '(NR==n){for(i=p;i<(q>NF?q:NF);++i) printf $i OFS; print $(q>NF?q:NF);exit}
```

**Retrieve characters `p` to `q` in paragraph `n`:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n"}(NR==n){print substr($0,p,q-p+1); exit}' file
```

**Retrieve `p`th character/word/sentence in paragraph `n`:**

```
# character
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}(NR==n){print substr($0,p,1); exit}'
# word
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}(NR==n){gsub(/\n/," ",$0);print $p; exit}' file
# sentence
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="[.?!]+";c=n}(NR==n){print $p; exit}' file
```